Non-homogeneous, non-linear recurrence relation simplification ft. Coefficients of power series
Consider an arbitrary sequence $b_p$ such that $(-1)^{b_p} \in \mathbb{R} \ \ \forall p\in\mathbb{N}$.
We know ,$$-1 = e^{i \pi} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{i^k {\pi}^k}{k!}$$
Exponentiating both sides to the power of $b_p$,
$$(-1)^{b_p} = \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{i^k {\pi}^k}{k!}\right)^{b_p} \\
\Rightarrow e^{i \pi b_p} = \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{i^k {\pi}^k}{k!}\right)^{b_p} \\
\Rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{i^k {\pi}^k {(b_p)}^k}{k!} = \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{i^k {\pi}^k}{k!}\right)^{b_p} $$
Now as mentioned here on Wikipedia, exponentiation of a formal power series is a well-defined operation as follows:
$$  \left(\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }a_{k}X^{k}\right)^{\!n}=\,\sum _{m=0}^{\infty }c_{m}X^{m}  $$
for some sequence $c_m$ such that:
$$ c_0 = (a_0)^n \\
c_{m} = {\frac {1}{ma_{0}}}\sum _{k=1}^{m}(kn-m+k)a_{k}c_{m-k} \ \ \ \ \ (m \geq 1)
$$
Applying this property to the RHS of the abovementioned equations, by setting $a_k = \frac{1}{k!}, n = b_p, c_m = c_k, X = i \pi$
$$
\Rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{i^k {\pi}^k {(b_p)}^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \left( \sum_{m=1}^{k} \frac{m(1+b_p) - k}{m!} c_{k-m} \right)
$$
By comparison of coefficients, it is clear that: $$c_k =  \sum_{m=1}^{k} \frac{m(1+b_p) - k}{m!} c_{k-m}  = \frac{(b_p)^k}{(k-1)!} $$
Direct evaluation at $m=1,2,3$ confirms this as well.
The question is, how does one go from the LHS of the above equation (that is the recurrence relation involving the sum) to the RHS? Is there no other method except a comparison of coefficients? I came up with the above sequence while playing around with non-linear recurrence relations, and it took me quite a while to come up with this solution.
I did try generating functions but it resulted in a mess beyond my comprehension. I have yet to try Z-transforms or come across some 'educated guess'. I will add my Z-transform attempt if it might result in something plausible.
Also, $-1$ isn't specific, it is just the first number that came to mind :)
Thank you very much in advance!

I see several issues with the question. Its first sentence suggests that we have a sequence $(b_p)_{p\in P}$ of complex numbers indexed by elements of some set $P$ such that $(-1)^{b_p}\in\mathbb R$ for each $p\in P$. But, as far as I see, next you deal with a single member $b_p$ of this sequence (as it seems that sometimes it typed wrong as $b_i$). Also the formula from Wikipedia for the exponentiation of a formal power series is provided for natural powers.

Right, thanks for pointing these things out, @AlexRavsky. I will make the needed edits

If you take a natural number $b_p$, then $(-1)^{b_p}$ is $-1$ or $1$ so writing `such that $(-1)^{b_p} \in \mathbb{R}$' is useless.

@ChristopheLeuridan seems like i misunderstood Alex's comment, I didn't mean to add that. Will remove it.

You are somewhat beating around the bush, because the purpose of formal series turns out to manipulate sequences as a whole through their (potentially non-convergent) generating functions instead of an element-wise treatment.
Short answer.
Let's restate your problem. Ultimately, you want to determine the sequence of coefficients $(c_m)_{m\in\Bbb{N}}$ defined from the relation
$$
\tag{$*$}
\sum_{m\in\Bbb{N}} c_mX^m = \left(\sum_{k\in\Bbb{N}} a_kX^k\right)^n,
$$
in the concrete case where $a_k = \frac{1}{k!}$. As said above, it can be done straightforwardly with the help of their respective generating functions. Indeed, one has :
$$
C(X) = \sum_{m\in\Bbb{N}} c_mX^m = \left(\sum_{k\in\Bbb{N}} a_kX^k\right)^n = A(X)^n = e^{nX},
$$
hence $c_m = \frac{n^m}{m!}$ by definition of the exponential series. QED
Long answer.
If you really desire to adopt an element-wise approach, the equality $(*)$ is translated as
$$
a_0m\,c_m = \sum_{k=1}^m (kn-m+k)a_kc_{m-k},
$$
together with the initial condition $c_0 = a_0^n$, as you stated. Again, generating functions is the way to go. The generating function associated to the left-hand side is related to the derivative of $C(X) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty c_mX^m$, because $XC'(X) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty mc_mX^m$, while the factor $a_kc_{m-k}$ on the right-hand side betrays the convolution of two formal series. The latter can be decomposed into two terms, namely
$$
\sum_{k=1}^m kna_kc_{m-k} = n\sum_{k=0}^m ka_kc_{m-k} \longrightarrow nXA'(X)C(X)
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^m (m-k)a_kc_{m-k} = \sum_{\ell:=m-k=0}^{m-1} \ell a_{m-\ell}c_\ell = \sum_{\ell=0}^m a_{m-\ell} \ell c_\ell - a_0mc_m \longrightarrow A(X)XC'(X) - a_0XC'(X),
$$
hence the following differential equation :
$$
a_0XC'(X) = nXA'(X)C(X) - (A(X)XC'(X) - a_0XC'(X)),
$$
which is simplified as
$$
C'(X) = \frac{nA'(X)}{A(X)}C(X) = nC(X),
$$
given that $A(X) = e^X$, and integrated as $C(X) = \alpha e^{nX}$, where the constant of integration $\alpha$ is given by $\alpha = C(0) = c_0 = a_0^n = 1$ in the present case. In the end, it allows us to conclude in the same way as in the short answer above.
